# Using an unsupported language in an app

Tags: java, android

I am creating an application that uses data downloaded from MySQL databases. It is necessary for the application to support Khmer (Cambodia) but I have found that Khmer is not one of the pre-installed languages on android.

My question is how can I continue to develop the application in a way that supports this language?

Thanks